# "Now is the time" followed by past tense verb

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

This morning I heard Jeremy Corbyn's speech at the Labour Conference.  Here is a section of that speech.  Can anyone tell me what tense he is using and why? 
"Now is the time that government ***took*** a more active role in restructuring our economy. Now is the time that corporate boardrooms ***were*** held accountable for their actions,  And now is the time that we ***developed*** a new model of economic management to replace the failed dogmas of neo-liberalism …"  Is this a Britishism?  (I am American.)  Thanking your all in advance for any insights you can offer.

Comment: He's trying to avoid what sounds like "subjunctive" to his speechwriters and "errors" to his constituents, trying to sound like the "folks".

Comment: I wouldn't vote for this. It sounds non-standard, a mix of usages. And I'm British.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm US, and I find it wholly unremarkable.

Comment: @StoneyB Note that Mr Corbyn has _not_ been voted in, in spite of the alternatives on offer.

Comment: Rhetorically, it is probably being used to suggest the relative remoteness of 'government' (compared to the speaker and audience, who are tight). I think he really ought to have switched to the present tense in the last sentence, though, because of the shift to *we*.

Comment: He's using the past tense form to refer to the non-past. This question is surely a duplicate of about half dozen on this site.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603360/2085).

Answer (score 3):

I am a US speaker—my native dialect is southern—and Mr. Corbyn employs this construction in the only way familiar to me, with the verb in its past form:

> It's time we **went** home.
>   It's time we **were** going.

I cannot recall ever encountering this with a present-form verb, although a version with a marked infinitive is common:

> It's time **to go** home.
>   It's time **to be** going.

Comment: But not 'now is the time we were going', surely? I don't know why 'now it is time we were going' works, but I think it is a different flavor of *now*. I can only use present tense in the here-and-now.

Answer (score 2):

["It’s time + subject + past verb form"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/it-s-time) can be used to refer to the present moment, which is the case here I think.

Comment: Argument from analogy is rarely safe in English, and I don't think it is here. And you don't sound sure yourself.